# Facebook fan page on iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

I want to show my facebook fan page inside of my iphone app. Can anyone suggest me the proper way to do that or show me any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the fan page url as follows,

.h

@interface socailNetworking : UIViewController 
{

IBOutlet UIWebView *socailNetworkingWeb;

}

@end

.m

-(void)facebook
{

self.navigationItem.title=@"FaceBook";
[socailNetworkingWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Gantec-Publishing-Solutions/131691573583238?sk=wall"]]];

}